# keras model.fit output - "val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.29846" - what does it mean by -inf?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training a CNN model using keras.

After end of each epoch, I save the weights as checkpoints if the validation accuracy has improved.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', 
save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

callbacks = [checkpoint]

#load checkpoints if existing
import os

num_of_epochs = 65
epochs_done = 0

if(os.path.exists(checkpoint_path)):
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    num_of_epochs = num_of_epochs - epochs_done
    print('checkpoints loaded')
```

When I restart training after stopping, this is how my first epoch output looks like.

```
Epoch 1/65
425/425 [==============================] - 224s 526ms/step - loss: 2.1739 - accuracy: 0.2939 - val_loss: 2.1655 - val_accuracy: 0.2985

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.29846, saving model to checkpoints-finetuning.hdf5
```

I noticed this happening at at the first epoch every time I restart training. Why does it happen? Does my checkpoint file get overwritten by worse accurate weights each time I restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the callback instance is recreated every time you run the script; it isn't saved with the model. As such, the first epoch will always begin from the default value which is either `np.Inf` or `-np.Inf` as per [this right here.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L683)